# Firebase Cloud Messaging Subscribe Multiple Tokens to a Topic

Tags: android, ios, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an app that allows users to create an account.  I then store user information in the Firebase Database. I also store all of the users device tokens in case they are using multiple devices with one account (iPhone, iPad, Android, etc).

When a user subscribes to a topic, I would like to be able to subscribe all of their associated device tokens to that topic and not just the device they are currently using.  Is there a way to specify a token when subscribing to a topic so that they will receive topic notifications on all of their devices.

Answer (score 0):

> *I also store all of the users device tokens in case they are **using multiple devices with one account (iPhone, iPad, Android, etc)**.*

I'm presuming from that statement, that you are using [Device Groups](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/notifications).

> *When a user subscribes to a topic, I would like to be able to subscribe all of their associated device tokens to that topic and not just the device they are currently using. Is there a way to specify a token when subscribing to a topic so that they will receive topic notifications on all of their devices.*

The way I'm thinking of how to do this, is via your server side. Check the connected tokens to your device group, then subscribe the tokens using the [batchAdd](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server#manage_relationship_maps_for_multiple_app_instances).

What I'm not sure is, if it is possible to [Subscribe a notification_key to a Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38114000/4625829) though.

Comment: It is not possible to subscribe a notification key to a topic.

Comment: Hi @ArthurThompson sir. Thanks for verifying the batch subscription :) Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the reply int j...  I must have overlooked Device Groups, because I wasn't using them, but certainly will now. Device Groups gets me very close to a solution.  If it was possible to subscribe the notification_key for a device group to a topic, that would solve my problem.  Too bad that won't work.

Comment: @Jeremy7918234 That would've been convenient. Hope they can add it next time. For the meantime, it seems the solution/workaround available is the one in my answer. Cheers!

Comment: Set user's topic name to his `userId` .... that way you can handle all of his devices.