# Subscribe a Device Group (notification_key) to a Topic

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've recently encountered this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38103241/4625829) where the general idea is how to subscribe a user to a topic, with multiple devices. I provided an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38113999/4625829), suggesting to make use of the Device Group, then doing the [batchAdd](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server#manage_relationship_maps_for_multiple_app_instances) on the server side.

But I was wondering if it was possible to subscribe to a topic using the device group `notification_key`?

I haven't seen anything that mentions something like that in the docs.
The notification key is described in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/notifications) as:

> All devices in a group share a common **notification key, which is the token that FCM uses to fan out messages to all devices in the group**.

So I thought maybe it was possible to use it. But can't find anything that mentions it though. I've looked around the community for any other similar posts, went through the docs, but most of it are just about subscribing a single device to a topic.

Was my answer to the post a good method? Or did I just miss something where there is already a process/flow on how to actually do this?

I haven't really tried it out myself, but it was the only way I could think of. I'm still studying about GCM & FCM and I would appreciate it a lot if someone that tried it before can shed some light about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot subscribe a device_group to a topic. The way to achieve this would be to subscribe the tokens associated with the device group to the topic either individually or in batch.

Comment: Hi @ArthurThompson sir. Thanks for verifying. :) Was wondering if there is any documentation that states this? Or not?

Comment: Not explicitly, but subscribing to topics require IID tokens which is stated explicitly.

Comment: So using an IID, it **would** be possible to subscribe a group to a topic?