# FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) send to multiple device group

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

From Firebase docs and StackOverflow questions, I understood that we can send Push Notifications to multiple devices through [Topic Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging) and [Device Group Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/device-group). But I would like to know if is there a way to trigger Push Notifications to multiple device group in a single FCM send request?

Basically, I don't want to invoke multiple requests for the same push notification message. And the reason why I have multiple device group is because there is of an upper cap on number members (i.e) to a notification_key.

And the reason for which I don't want to publish the message to topics is basically due to my requirement constraint. My requirement is " I have some alert message generated in back-end and the same has to be sent only to few users (**A user can log into multiple devices**) and the issue that I could foresee with the topic is I could not afford for a dynamic property in topics.

If there is a way to implement with topics please give your suggestions.

Comment: Sorry. I'm a bit confused. What do you mean by *there is a upper cap on number members (i.e) to a notification_key*?

Comment: As per the doc The maximum number of members allowed for a notification_key is 20 stated in https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/device-group. I assume it as maximum of 20 devices can be grouped in one device group. I have not tried to register more than 5 devices in dev environment but in reality it is very much possible.

Comment: It's still unclear what you're really asking here. You say the reason you used DGM is because it has an *upper cap* on the number of members. But Topic Messaging has **no limit** to the number of possible subscribers.

Comment: The reason why I don't go for topic is my "Push notification messages are intended only to a certain set of devices or users" If I use Topics then the messages will be delivered to all devices. If there is a way to restrict messages getting displayed in notification through topics please let me know.

Comment: I think you misunderstand Topic Messaging. The recipients of Topic Messaging are the only ones that are subscribed to it. Sample: Topic1 has 5 subscribers, only those 5 will receive it. For Topic2, it has 3 subscribers then only those 3 (different from the 5 from Topic1) will receive the message.

Comment: @AL, please Apologies me for not posting my requirement properly. Here is my requirement, " I have some alert generated in backend and the same has to be sent only to few users (a user can log in to multiple devices)" The issue that I could see foresee with the topic is
(count) I can not afford for a dynamic property in topic. I'm not sure if you understood my requirement.

Comment: Hi Vivek. I suggest you edit your post instead of commenting to avoid it being deleted by the system.

Comment: I've seen the edit. I'm not sure what you mean by *I can not afford for a dynamic property in topic.*.

Comment: Apologies once again, When I write subscribers for the topic I'll not know to which topic this particular device has to listen. Can I able to tell the client/SDK to which topic it should listen dynamically. I'm afraid whether I'm still clear on my requirement. Really appreciate your efforts to understand my requirement.

Comment: I'm still unable to get it clearly. Can you site an example scenario in your post? Do edit in your post and I'll take a look at it later. Avoid too many comments so that the system won't delete it.

Comment: Im may be mistaken, but I think this question is the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38114000/subscribe-a-device-group-notification-key-to-a-topic ?

Answer (score 6):

After reading so many comments I am not sure if I got your question correctly but as per my understanding what you require is **Multicast Messaging**.

Instead of specifying the ***to*** key you may simply specify ***registration_ids*** key in your fcm request.

***registration_ids*** *(String array)* :

This parameter specifies a list of devices (registration tokens, or IDs) receiving a multicast message. It must contain at least 1 and at most 1000 registration tokens.
Use this parameter only for multicast messaging, not for single recipients. Multicast messages (sending to more than 1 registration tokens) are allowed using HTTP JSON format only.

For more info refer [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-json).

Comment: But this comes under legacy HTTP Server Protocol. What's the alternate?

Answer (score 5):

You need to handle it on server side. You can use firebase group device notification.

For the first token, create a notification key using create operation.
For rest of the token, use add operation to add to the same notification key.

Note - it is limit to 20 devices.
For ref check below link.
https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/notifications

Comment: so suppose an user login in an app with email & password. Then needs to create a notification key with email as the notification_key_name. In that case what will be the 'registration_ids' to pass? In doc it is mentioned as 1,5,15 etc

Answer (score 1):

Currently from what I could understand reading the FCM doc they don't allow sending notification to Multiple device groups in single request like they do with `registration_ids` so I would suggest to use topic to group users like we do with devices

Something like this
When user login subscribe the user to a topic with it's own `userId` or some other unique identifier of the user
So same user can be reached at same topic which is named after it's `userId`

There wouldn't be any `registration_ids` limit (1-1000) so this would help in case you have more than 1000 `registration_ids` to send in request

Answer (score 0):

Looks like those who need Multicast Messaging should stay with legacy API until an update of the v1 is released. Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1:  ***Any apps that use device group messaging or multicast messaging, however, may prefer to wait for future versions of the API. HTTP v1 does not ...***