# FCM, NodeJS - Alternative for subscribing to multiple topics

Tags: node.js, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Users may have multiple devices. And they may subscribe to multiple channels. Each channel is a topic (from FCM's perspective).

When the use signs in from a new device, the device has to be subscribed to all the channels (could be hundreds). Making potentially hundreds of API calls sounds like a bad idea.

Also, it seems [subscribing a device group to a topic is not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38114000/subscribe-a-device-group-notification-key-to-a-topic) either.

Is there any alternative (and cheaper) way to subscribe a client device to multiple topics?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no other alternative to subscribe a client to a topic otber than the usual client side subscription(`subscribeToTopic()`) and using the [InstanceID API](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server#create_relationship_maps_for_app_instances).

In your use case, it seems that somehow, the topics are private for some reason. In general, topics should only be used for messages that could be received publicly.

One way I could think of simply maintaining the groups on your own server, and removing and adding the corresponding token when needed. Although this may still be heavy depending on how many groups you'll add/remove the token from.